# Was the blacksmith of the Atlantean sword knowledgeable of the Riddle of Steel?

Tags: conan-the-barbarian-1982

The Riddle of Steel is well known as the central to the plot of John Milius's 1982 movie: *Conan the Barbarian*. Knowing that Cimmerians — from whom Conan is descended — descended from Atlanteans who were warriors and hunters and advanced technologically, it is plausible that the teachings of Conan's father's (who was a blacksmith) to young Conan about the power of steel were learned via storytelling from their Atlantean ancestors.

I ask if there is (canon or legend) evidence in Conan's lore of the blacksmith — he who crafted the Atlantean sword discovered by Conan the Barbarian, with carved hieroglyphics, and that shattered Conan's father's sword and that once belonged to an 8-foot tall Atlantean King or General — to have been knowledgeable of the Riddle of Steel?

[image: Conan the Barbarian and Atlantean Sword]

Comment: Just to be clear, are you asking whether the blacksmith was familiar with the concept that the owner of the sword is the greater power than the sword itself?

Comment: @FuzzyBoots - I am asking if behind forging the sword, the Atlantean blacksmith embraced a philosophy related to the Riddle or a thinking that gave birth to the Riddle.

Comment: @FuzzyBoots - Noting that both Conan's father and Thulsa Doom were wrong about the answer to the riddle. It's not the quality of the steel that's important, nor the intent of the flesh that wields it. The supreme power is *both combined*.

Comment: There is that. Conan's father's sword doesn't break until it wielded by Thulsa Doom.

Comment: *Conan watched the gory object fall into the purple shadows of the dying day. Then, half to himself, he spoke: “My father was the light of day; Thulsa Doom, my night. Yet in one thing he spoke true. What matters is not the steel within the blade, but the steel within the man.”* - Novelisation